# ORA-02289: sequence doesn't exist

Tags: oracle

I created a sequence EMP_SEQ then added a column to a table with EMP_SEQ as column as below:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD EMP_SEQ;
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET EMP_SEQ = EMP_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MODIFY(EMP_SEQ DEFAULT ON NULL EMP_SEQ.NEXTVAL);
```

Later I had to rename the sequence to EMP_SEQ_AUTO_INC and column name of EMPLOYEE table to the same as below:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE COLUMN EMP_SEQ TO EMP_SEQ_AUTO_INC;
RENAME EMP_SEQ TO EMP_SEQ_AUTO_INC;
```

And now the ORA 02289 occurs when I try to insert data into the table with column_name EMP_SEQ_AUTO_INC.

Should I complete the below steps with new column name to overcome this error:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET EMP_SEQ_AUTO_INC = EMP_SEQ_AUTO_INC.NEXTVAL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MODIFY(EMP_SEQ_AUTO_INC DEFAULT ON NULL EMP_SEQ_AUTO_INC.NEXTVAL);
```

Comment: Looks to me like the entire issue stems from you mis-guided attempt to have the column name the same as the sequence used to populate it.  Why are you doing this?  Having two different objects with the same name will just be a great source of confusion down the road.

Answer (score 0):

That's not Oracle 11g, it doesn't support syntax you used. I suggest you fix the database version tag.

---

Anyway: with all modifications you made, you'll just need to re-run

```
ALTER TABLE employee MODIFY
  (emp_seq_auto_inc DEFAULT ON NULL emp_seq_auto_inc.NEXTVAL);
```

and that's all. No need to update rows once again, you won't get anything *new* because values already exist, and sequence was just renamed (so it continues with its values, i.e. you won't get duplicates which might happen if you dropped it and created a new one).